# PowerAutomate recurrence frequency

Tags: azure, power-automate

I would like to know how the frequency works in the flows.
The microsoft documentation says it has a maximun frequency of 1 minute (paid version).

Imagine I set up a trigger "on insert" with a SQL Server table:

1. Within a minute, 50 users insert a record.
2. The very first one will trigger the flow.

What will happen next? Upon 1 minute will the rest 49 execute one after the other? Or will it take 49 minutes to complete?

Comment: Just to double check. Are you talking about a recurrence trigger action where the flows triggers with a certain frequency? Or are you talking about a webhook/trigger action like When an item is created (v2), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#when-an-item-is-created-(v2). In case of the latter it should trigger directly after each other. The completion time depends on the design of the rest of your flow.

Comment: I am not referring to the recurrence triggers. If you want specifics... I am referring to the "when item inserted v2" in  SQL Server.